# Making 2 networks talk to each other

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wired-networking

I live in an apartment building. I'm looking at this as a theoretical project and I want to know if it's achievable or not.

The apartment building has a network intercom device. It has an IP address so I am under the impression is part of a LAN network. What I want to do is try and use the signal received on the device to be broadcasted on my local wifi network. I want to understand what requests/responses are sent and then control my doorbell from my phone or a web browser.

Is there some device where I can receive that signal and send it to my local network?

I can reverse engineer the request and response once I know how to get the my local wifi network to talk to the main LAN network.

Comment: In general, you can just plug your computer into 2 networks and then your computer can talk to both networks. No need to connect them together. You didn't really explain what you are trying to connect to. Does it have an Ethernet jack on it, or is it wi-fi?

Answer (score 2):

It's technically possible, but as you're tampering with someone else's network (which I strongly suggest you *not* do in the first place) you need to be careful to not *interfere* with it. Network communications are **always bidirectional;** avoid thinking of IP networking as "signal being received" like it's a TV.

So this rules out the usual suggestions like a "LAN-to-LAN connection" with typical home routers. You definitely don't to leak *your own* "signal" (e.g. your LAN DHCP server) into the intercom network or to create a network loop by accident.

If you only want your *computer* to be able to receive the data, then you don't really want to have the two networks talk to each other *at all* – instead the computer can be connected to two independent networks at the same time. If it has no free Ethernet ports, it doesn't cost much to add another one (either via USB or PCI-E).

Insert an Ethernet switch between the doorbell and the cable that goes to it, then connect your computer directly to the switch. You'll probably want to get a switch that has a "port mirroring" feature, as otherwise it will not send you *any* of the data that the doorbell is sending or receiving. (Upon enabling port mirroring, you'll probably find the traffic is encrypted using TLS or something similar anyway.)

For something more permanent (accessing both networks from your LAN without them interfering with each other), you need a router. Many "home wireless" routers probably *won't* be suitable out of the box (their "WAN/LAN" assumptions run too deep) although OpenWRT would generally work when carefully set up; this is generally where you want a generic "enterprise" router whose configuration you build *up* (I usually go either for standard Linux PCs, or for Mikrotik products with their RouterOS).